# How to read and write to files in Mono

Tags: vb.net, mono, .net

I am using Mono on Ubuntu 12.10. My application requires reading and writing from a text document and checking if specific files exist. I can't determine whether or not Mono supports this, but the following code causes the application not to run at all.

```
Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "\Data\programdata.txt")

Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1

    Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add(objReader.ReadLine())

Loop
```

EDIT: Resolved, I just forgot to use forward slashes.

Comment: "not ... working" - what exactly happens when you try it? Also, do you realize that directories are not separated with backslahes in Linux?

Comment: Wow, that was the whole issue. It is fixed now.

Comment: Please add your resolution as an answer and then accept that answer, so future visitors will clearly see that the problem has been solved. Note that the proper solution would be using [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx), which will automatically insert the appropriate directory level separator characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux uses forward slashes as the path separator, where as I was using the backwards slash on Windows. This caused the application to crash on Mono for Linux. When changed to the forward slash, the application ran fine.